# How can I concatenate np.arrays into a DataFrame in for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am getting error while appending np.arrays into a DataFrame. Each np.array has varying length, so np.vstack will not work. What is the best way to deal with this?

Also, "y" needs to be sorted accordingly and the data I processed comes with different initial point --- I think it is easier to sort in DataFrame, but I haven't got to that point yet. Unless there's other suggestion? Thank you!

```
# For example:

# In "n" loop, I will get y0, x0. Then in "n+1" loop, I will get y1, x1 and "n+1" loop to get y2, x2, etc.
y0 = np.array([6,7,8,9])
y1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
x0 = np.array([600, 700, 800, 900])
x1 = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])

# Ultimately, the DataFrame should return this:
print(df)

   y    x  
0  1    0.1
1  2    0.2
2  3    0.3
3  4    0.4
4  5    0.5
5  6    600
6  7    700
7  8    800
8  9    900
```

My current code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"data_y":[], "data_x":[]})

for i in range(100):
    
    # Initiate lists
    data_y = []
    data_x = []

    # Data processed using list
    data_y, data_x = ....

    # Convert list to np.array
    data_y, data_x = ....

    # Compile data to DataFrame
    df["data_y"] = data_y.tolist()
    df["data_x"] = data_x.tolist()

# ValueError: Length of values (111) does not match length of index (256)
```

Comment: is `data_y` and  `data_x`have same lenght each time ?

Comment: @HamzaNABIL: Yes. data_y and data_x always have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame(np.c_[np.r_[y1, y0], np.r_[x1, x0]], columns = ['y','x'])
     y      x
0  1.0    0.1
1  2.0    0.2
2  3.0    0.3
3  4.0    0.4
4  5.0    0.5
5  6.0  600.0
6  7.0  700.0
7  8.0  800.0
8  9.0  900.0
```

---

In case you must pass in `y0` then `y1` you could create the df and sort by `y`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.c_[np.r_[y0,y1], np.r_[x0,x1]], columns = ['y','x']).sort_values('y')
     y      x
4  1.0    0.1
5  2.0    0.2
6  3.0    0.3
7  4.0    0.4
8  5.0    0.5
0  6.0  600.0
1  7.0  700.0
2  8.0  800.0
3  9.0  900.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that it erases the values of `df`  each time.

You can create a `df` in each iteration using `data_x` and `data_y` and store it in a list. Concatenate all the results at the end.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def processed_data():
  # your logic
  return [1, 3, 5], [0.2, 0.4, 0.6]

dfs_list = []
for i in range(3):
    data_x, data_y = processed_data()
    dfs_list.append(
        pd.DataFrame({"data_y": data_y, "data_x": data_x})
    )

df = pd.concat(dfs_list) 


print(df)
```

output :

```
   data_y  data_x
0     0.2       1
1     0.4       3
2     0.6       5
0     0.2       1
1     0.4       3
2     0.6       5
0     0.2       1
1     0.4       3
2     0.6       5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [138]: y0 = np.array([6,7,8,9])
     ...: y1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
     ...: x0 = np.array([600, 700, 800, 900])
     ...: x1 = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
```

Your 4 arrays can be joined horizontally (on their one axis):

```
In [139]: y=np.hstack((y0,y1))
     ...: x=np.concatenate((x0,x1)) # same
In [140]: y,x
Out[140]: 
(array([6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([6.e+02, 7.e+02, 8.e+02, 9.e+02, 1.e-01, 2.e-01, 3.e-01, 4.e-01,
        5.e-01]))
```

Those `x1` floats make the whole `x` array float.

Now find how to sort the `y` values

```
In [141]: idx=y.argsort()
In [142]: idx
Out[142]: array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```

And make a 2d array from the sorted values - again with float values:

```
In [143]: xy=np.stack((y[idx],x[idx]), axis=1)

In [144]: xy
Out[144]: 
array([[1.e+00, 1.e-01],
       [2.e+00, 2.e-01],
       [3.e+00, 3.e-01],
       [4.e+00, 4.e-01],
       [5.e+00, 5.e-01],
       [6.e+00, 6.e+02],
       [7.e+00, 7.e+02],
       [8.e+00, 8.e+02],
       [9.e+00, 9.e+02]])

In [145]: import pandas as pd
In [146]: df=pd.DataFrame(xy)
```

The dataframe displays them better:

```
In [147]: df
Out[147]: 
     0      1
0  1.0    0.1
1  2.0    0.2
2  3.0    0.3
3  4.0    0.4
4  5.0    0.5
5  6.0  600.0
6  7.0  700.0
7  8.0  800.0
8  9.0  900.0
```

Better yet keep `y` and `x` separate when making the frame

```
In [148]: df=pd.DataFrame({'y':y[idx], 'x':x[idx]})

In [149]: df
Out[149]: 
   y      x
0  1    0.1
1  2    0.2
2  3    0.3
3  4    0.4
4  5    0.5
5  6  600.0
6  7  700.0
7  8  800.0
8  9  900.0
```

`x` could be created as object dtype, and retain the mix of int and floats.

```
In [150]: x=np.concatenate((x0,x1), dtype=object)[idx]
In [151]: x
Out[151]: array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 600, 700, 800, 900], dtype=object)
```